# Auto node drawing tool in QGIS

Tags: qgis

I'm new to QGIS and am more familiar with MapInfo.

I've been playing around with QGIS to do some habitat mapping based on aerial photography and was wondering if there is a feature in QGIS which automatically draws a poly line or polygon whilst you move the cursor over the screen?

MapInfo has a handy feature called 'auto node' which does this by dropping nodes constantly as the cursor moves. It's useful as you can get very smooth lined polygons which are difficult to achieve if you have to click the mouse everytime to drop a node.

Can QGIS do this???

Thanks!

Steve

Comment: I think there is a "freehand" plugin you could give a try.

Comment: @Under Out of curiosity, is there a central clearinghouse for QGIS add-ins? If so, we can create pointers to it from this site in various ways, such as through a meta thread or even our FAQ. That could help out a lot of people with questions like this one.

Comment: @whuber In QGIS 1.8, there will be only one official plugin repo anymore: http://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/. It will still be possible to add other, non-official ones (as far as I know).

Answer (score 5):

Underdark is right. You want the "Freehand Editing" Tool.